# TSQL Weighted Average

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a TSQL function to calculate weighted average cost for inventory calculation. So given the following table structure

```
ProductId | DatePurchased | Qty | Cost
--------- | ------------- | --- | ----
1         | Jan 1         | 10  | 1.50
1         | Jan 10        | 5   | 2.00
1         | Jan 20        | 7   | 2.50
```

Now if on Jan 21 someone purchased 15 the weighted cost would be

((7 * 2.5) + (5 * 2.0) + (3 * 1.5)) / 15 = 2.13

Basically, that is the average cost of 7 from Jan 20, 5 from Jan 10 and 3 from Jan 1.

I am sure this can be done with some kind of recursive CTE, but by someone smarter than me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A weight average is simple:

```
select sum(qty * cost) / sum(qty)
from t;
```

You are looking for something else.  Perhaps an "allocated" average:

```
select sum(case when cume_qty - qty < 15 then qty * cost
                else (cume_qty - 15) * cost
           end) as allocated_average
from (select t.*,
             sum(qty) over (partition by productid order by date desc) as cume_qty
      from t
     ) t
where cume_qty - qty < 15 and
      cume_qty >= 15;
```

Comment: It is based on the description here
http://www.accounting-basics-for-students.com/fifo-method.html

Comment: @Craig . . . You are using the LIFO method, which appears to be distinct from the "weighted average" method.

Comment: You are correct (accounting maybe not my strong point). The Weighted Average seems to be the least accurate IMO, but that is what the client wants.